# C# regex with the pattern

Tags: c#, regex

How can I declare regex pattern in c#. Pattern starts with [111 abc.def.ghi 111]

In the above format only the numeric values may be different but all the rest remain same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example to get the two blocks of digits from your string `[111 abc.def.ghi 111]`

```
string regexPattern = @"\d+";
string input = @"[111 abc.def.ghi 111]";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, regexPattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", m.Value, m.Index);
}
```

Comment: Can we do it in one line without forecach? Because most of the text remains same just the numbers will change. Any suggestion?

Comment: your code is accepting even if the input is just [111]. But i need to make sure that abc.def.ghi exists too. any suggestion please?